# Leopard Mail app keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, mail.app

I've recently switched to Chrome for developing and have thus started using the build-in Developer Tools instead of my previously preferred Firebug workflow. Just today I found a keyboard shortcut (Command-Shift-I) that jumps straight to Inspect Element rather than just opening the Developer Tools like Command-Option-I does.

The problem I'm having is that this shortcut also opens the Mail app, which I do not use. I've looked in the Keyboard Shortcuts preferences and I don't see the aforementioned shortcut anywhere. Anybody know where I can disable this shortcut?

Comment: I don't know where you found the Command+Shift+I to Inspect Element.  In Chrome, if you go to File, right above Print you see Command+Shift+I is Email Page Location.

Comment: You're right. Somehow I got this confused with Command + Shift + C as zevlag pointed out below. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  Will open up the inspector, and let you click an object to Inspect.

https://superuser.com/questions/175529/google-chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-view-resources-inspect-element

Comment: My confusion. See comment above, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

hotkeys for Chrome on Mac OS X ([from here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts)):

- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open Developer Tools
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to toggle Inspect Element mode.